# How to play .mid Sound in resources using windows media player in c#

Tags: c#, windows-media-player

I want to play a mid sound which embedded in my resources file , its in byte , I searched a lot I found most answers like [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/413a4ed9-acbc-468d-8119-be2db5e4de62/play-an-embedded-resource-sound-file) ,I changed it to my resouces like this

```
 Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.music.mid");
```

but it gives me an exception of null

, waht I excactly want is to read this sound , if in byte or another alternative way possible .

Comment: Use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourcenames()` to find exact name

Comment: But it does not support String argument

Comment: `stream` is null. that's your problem right?

Comment: Yes that is my problem , I tested above code it says , `System.Reflects.Assembly Could not found` , while I imported it above my class

Comment: Post the error and your using directive too

Comment: When I copy and paste your code , it wants System.Reflects to be imported , when I import this , a red underline be drawn under `.GetManifestResourcenames()` , the error says  `System.Reflects.Assembly Could not found`

Comment: There is nothing like `System.Reflects.Assembly`. It will be `System.Reflection.Assembly`. Your resource name may be wrong. Look at my first comment. Call this `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourcenames()` and see what is the result you're getting

Answer (score 0):

If you simply set file's build action as Embedded Resource you can access it using:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("WindowsFormsApplication1.music.mid")
```

If it doesn't work use this code to find the exact name:

```
For Each strResource As String In Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames()
    MsgBox(strResource)
Next strResource
```

Comment: The first code says `Obejct is no set to an instans of the object` when i print the resource out

ans the second one is not working

Comment: The second snippet of code is written in VB.NET but you can easily translate it to C#.

Comment: This works , but it gives me some names till resources , does not give me resources content

Comment: The second snippet of code gave you the exact name of the resource. You have to use this name in the first snippet of code.

Comment: Thank you , its working now , It gave me a stream , now how to get the url from that stream?

Comment: Follow every steps in the link you posted. You simply have to create a file and pass his path to WMP. Maybe the biggest problem here is embedding a WindowsMediaPlayer object in your solution but this is another question (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562852%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Without using WMP you can also try to create a file with your Stream and then call Process.Start(<path to your file>) to open it with your default program for .mid file.